# Why should I care where a question was migrated from?

Tags: discussion, migration

Why do we use such a large banner to announce where a migrated question came from?

[image]
Does this have any influence over whether someone should or can answer the question? This is a very prominent reminder of the migration, yet all it tells me is that the person asking the question put it in the wrong place, which I don't care about. Why not make this a comment added by the system during migration, or change the text next to the user's picture from "asked 4 hours ago" to "asked 4 hours ago (migrated 4 minutes ago)". Better still, why not just get rid of it?

Comment: Well, if the OP doesn't have an account where the question now lives you have a means of knowing where to find them.  I know that's been useful for me on occasion, but I admit, not often.

Answer (score 5):

Because a question that was asked, viewed, commented on, and possibly drew some answers on a sister site before being migrated is a different beast than a "fresh" question that was literally just asked.

The "migrated" banner is an important callout as to the context of a migrated post's content prior to being migrated. It quickly clues everyone in on the "story" of the post so things are less confusing.

Comment: I still don't see why it matters to me in why or how I should answer a question.

Comment: By that logic we shouldn't display comments either.

Comment: @j08691 It adds context.  It explains comments such as "that type of question doesn't belong here" or "that should be posted on meta", which would be confusing after a migration.

Comment: @Servy - I don't mind the information appearing there entirely, however I fail to see the need for it being displayed so prominently.

Comment: @j08691, it's not for the answerer; it's for the *reader*, who sees comments and migrated answers that may be substantially out of whack with the site he's reading them on.